# How to hide the mouse cursor in Haskell Gloss

Tags: haskell, mouse-cursor, gloss

Is it possible to hide the cursor using Gloss in Haskell? We want to replace the player with the mouse position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality isn't exposed by gloss: it would be more easily achievable if the `Internal` modules were exposed (by using eg. [`playWithBackendIO`](https://github.com/benl23x5/gloss/blob/master/gloss/Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Game.hs) and some custom instances of [`Backend`](https://github.com/benl23x5/gloss/blob/master/gloss/Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Backend/GLUT.hs) to hide the cursor). If you really want this functionality, it'd be best to [fork the project](https://github.com/benl23x5/gloss) and add the functionality you want.

---

There are workarounds without modifying the original package though: when using any of the `...IO` functions, we can perform arbitrary `IO` actions inside the functions we pass in, which allows us to modify the state of the backend.

I'm going to use `displayIO` here for simplicity, but this works for any of the modes like `playIO` etc.

```
import Prelude hiding (init)
import Control.Monad
import Data.IORef
import Data.StateVar
import Graphics.Gloss
import Graphics.Gloss.Interface.IO.Display
import qualified Graphics.UI.GLUT.Window as Glut

init :: IO ()
init = Glut.cursor $= Glut.None

render :: IORef Bool -> IO Picture
render doneInit = do
    needsInit <- not <$> readIORef doneInit
    when needsInit $ do
        init
        writeIORef doneInit True
    return $ color white $ circle 30

controllerCallback :: Controller -> IO ()
controllerCallback _ = return ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let disp = InWindow "test" (800, 600) (0, 0)
    initVar <- newIORef False
    displayIO disp black (render initVar) controllerCallback
```

The vital piece is `Glut.cursor $= Glut.None`, which sets GLUT's [`cursor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLUT-2.7.0.14/docs/Graphics-UI-GLUT-Window.html#v:cursor) value using StateVar's `$=` function and automatically updates the glut context. We only want to run this once, so we use an `IORef` to keep track of whether we've run it before.

Finally, this doesn't work for the GLFW backend. gloss uses a [very old version of GLFW-b which doesn't support anything to do with cursor modes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLFW-b-0.0.2.2/docs/Graphics-UI-GLFW.html). [More modern versions do](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLFW-b-3.2.1.0/docs/Graphics-UI-GLFW.html), but I've not been able to find a way to get the `Window` instance as Gloss just discards it.